# SQL BigQuery Using Partition By on multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partitioning

I have the following table
Transaction Table

| USERID | TRANSACTION_DATE | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2021-05-03 | A |
| 112 | 2021-07-04 | C |
| 111 | 2021-08-21 | A |
| 113 | 2021-07-01 | B |
| 114 | 2021-07-09 | A |

I want to get a summary it so that I can get the MIN(TRANSACTION_DATE) for each product for each customer (basically the first date each customer started buying each of the product) like below.

Note: Not all customers have bought all the products

Desired Output:

| USERID | Product | FIRST_BOUGHT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | 2021-05-01 |
| 111 | B | 2021-03-01 |
| 111 | D | 2021-11-07 |
| 112 | A | 2021-05-09 |
| 112 | C | 2021-06-01 |

I have so far tried below but it isn't giving the expected result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT USERID, 
PRODUCT, 
MIN(TRANSACTION_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY USERID,PRODUCT ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE) AS FIRST_BOUGHT, 
FIRST_VALUE(PRODUCT) OVER(PARTITION BY USERID,PRODUCT ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE) AS Product
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select userid, product, min(transaction_date) as first_bought
FROM Table1
GROUP BY userid, product
```